# chance that a 6 digit number includes a certain number a certain number of times

Tags: probability

i feel like I should know this but i just can't wrap my head around this:

I want to know the chance/likelihood that a 6 digit number (leading 0s allowed, so 1,000,000 possibilities in total) includes a certain number, lets say 3, exactly 1 time, exactly 2 times, and at least 3 times. It doesn't matter if they are consecutive or where in the six digit number they occur

I first thought it would be 1 (specific number chance) * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 and for two times that number its 1 * 1 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9. (both devided by 1,000,000 to get the probability) but that just doesn't seem right...

how would I calculate this?

Comment: It looks like a binomial distribution

Comment: Suppose we were talking about our number having two $1$'s.  The calculation $1\cdot 1\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 9$ is the number of ways that the **first** digit is a $1$ and the **second** digit is a $1$ and the rest of the digits are not $1$'s, where we are very specifically only talking about the first digit and the second digit being ones.  This counts results like `112345` and `117755` and `110000` and so on.  It does *not* count any of the outcomes where the two $1$'s were in positions different than the first two spots such as `000011` or `100001` or `651431` etc...

Comment: You want $~\displaystyle \frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$ where $D = (10)^6.~$  Normally, there are $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}$ ways of selecting $k$ objects (i.e. digit positions) out of $n$, sampling without replacement, where the order of selection is irrelevant.  The question is, if $k$ *slots* are reserved for the 3's, in how many ways can the other $(6-k)$ slots be filled?

Comment: Combining JMoravitz and user2661923 comments one can get $p=\frac{9^{n-k} {n\choose k}}{10^n}$, $n$ -- number of digits number, $k$ -- exact number of times for certain digit.